# Overlay : filesystem not supported on lowerdir

Tags: filesystems, mount, overlayfs, union-mount

I tried to mount an external storage device (a usb flash drive) with overlay (as the lowerdir the usb and as upper a temporary ramdisk)

```
mkdir /data

mkdir /data/lower
mkdir /data/rw
mkdir /data/root
```

Then creating the ramdisk

```
mount -t tmpfs none /data/rw
mkdir /data/rw/upper
mkdir /data/rw/work
```

I mounted the usb device

```
mount -t vfat /dev/sdb1 /data/lower
```

To finally use overlay :

```
mount -t overlay -o lowerdir=/data/lower,upperdir=/data/rw/upper,workdi=/data/rw/work none /data/root
```

Which give me the folowwing error

> wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on overlay,
>          missing codepage or helper program, or other error
>
> overlayfs: filesystem on '/data/lower' not supported

But according to the [documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/overlayfs.txt)

> The lower filesystem can be any filesystem supported by Linux and does
>   not need to be writable

Is there a link with automount and if so how I can fix it ?

Comment: I suspect that the documentation is lying and doesn't support *any filesystem* as written. Of course replacing vfat with ext4 works. Couldn't find something to confirm this (looking at sources would probably, but too much effort)

Answer (score 2):

It took some digging, but the overlay filesystem driver [considers certain dentry flags "weird"](https://lkml.kernel.org/linux-ext4/CAOQ4uxgPXBazE-g2v=T_vOvnr_f0ZHyKYZ4wvn7A3ePatZrhnQ@mail.gmail.com/T/) (via [`ovl_dentry_weird`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/fs/overlayfs/util.c#L120)) and refuses to mount in the associated directories. Common cause is case-folding filesystems -- these will always be flagged as weird.